# Why is universal instantiation justified for an empty domain?

Tags: logic

Let's have our domain be the empty set. Since there are no x that aren't P, we have that  ∀xPx is true. But ∀xPx |= Pa is true, and so we should have Pa. But we are in the empty set and we don't have any individual thing for P to be true of. So why is Pa true for the empty set? For the same reason I also don't understand why ∀xPx |= ∃xPx is the case.

Comment: See [Free Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/)

Answer (score 2):

In fact "∀xPx ⊨ ∃xPx" is **not** true if our semantics allows for empty structures (perhaps more simply, "∀∈(()) ⊨ ∃∈(())" is simply false regardless of whether we permit the empty structure).

Similarly, the assertion of "∀xPx ⊨ Pa" tacitly assumes that the domain is nonempty (otherwise we can't even have closed terms like "a" refer to anything).

If you're interested in seeing logic treated to carefully allow for empty domains *(as well as possibly-non-referring terms, which I think is more interesting by far)*, the relevant term is **free logic**. Most presentations of first-order logic however simply take as an assumption that the domain is nonempty.